# Please tell VertexShader Error Solution

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Students that use OpenGL.
Do not speak English well.
So please understand.

There is currently a problem

```
#version 400
layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 VertexNormal;
layout (location = 2) in mat4 instance_ModelMatrix [3];
```

The VertexShader Code.
Code above , but it is run

```
layout (location = 2) in mat4 instance_ModelMatrix [3];
```

->

```
layout (location = 2) in mat4 instance_ModelMatrix [4];
```

With this changing run

> Attribute instance_ModelMatrix is ​​a matrix or array, and there is no room to insert it at the bound generic attribute channel.
>   Out of resource error.

This brings up an error .

Is there any way I want to use the current arrangement made ​​more than 60

Thank you look at the question

Answer (score 3):

### Why it doesn't work

The maximum number of attributes is determined by `GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS`, this is different for every implementation but must be at least 16 (so it should work...?).  You can get the value using `glGetIntegerv()`:

```
int maxVertexAttribs;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS, &maxVertexAttribs);
```

Since each `mat4` counts as four attributes, and each `vec3` counts as one, the following code uses uses 14 attributes:

```
#version 400
layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 VertexNormal;
layout (location = 2) in mat4 instance_ModelMatrix [3];
```

In this code, `instance_ModelMatrix` will actually use locations 2 through 13.  When you change the array size:

```
#version 400
layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 VertexNormal;
layout (location = 2) in mat4 instance_ModelMatrix [4];
```

This uses 18 vertex attributes, with `instance_ModelMatrix` in slots 2 through 17.  My guess is that the maximum number of vertex attributes on your system is 16, so this doesn't fit.

### Solution

If you want to use a lot of per-instance data, you will have to use uniforms, uniform buffer objects, or buffer textures.  [Uniform buffer objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) are probably the right fit for your application.  You can then use `gl_InstanceID` as an index into your instance data.

Comment: The minimum for `MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS` is 16 in OpenGL 4.0, which the OP appears to be using based on the shader version. Certainly looks like this is the limit for the specific implementation.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I think I was looking at the wrong man pages.