# Intel HD Graphics: Shader link error: "Out of resource error." because of gl_ClipVertex

Tags: opengl, glsl, intel

I just found that the following minimum OpenGL GLSL Vertex Shader fails to link on **Intel HD Graphics** cards with the GLSL link error **"Out of resource error."** as soon as the Vertex Shader source code contains the line `gl_ClipVertex = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;`. The same Shader compiles and links fine on NVIDIA or ATI graphics cards.

Does anyone know what might causing the link error on **Intel HD Graphics** cards?

Python script:

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *         
from OpenGL.GL   import *       
from OpenGL.GL   import shaders 

VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE = """
#version 110

void main(void)
{
  gl_Position = ftransform();
  gl_ClipVertex = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex; // Comment this line to link on Intel HD Graphics
  gl_FrontColor = vec4(1.0);
}"""

def main():
    glutInit(sys.argv)
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH)
    glutInitWindowSize(800,600)
    glutCreateWindow('IntelHDGraphicsClipPlanes')
    glutDisplayFunc(render)

    glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0)

    VERTEX_SHADER = shaders.compileShader(VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    shader = shaders.compileProgram(VERTEX_SHADER)

    shaders.glUseProgram(shader)
    glutMainLoop()
    return

def render():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glutSwapBuffers()
    return

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Python script output:
[image: Python script output]

Platform:
I am experiencing this behavior on various platforms with Intel HD Graphics cards but I am primarily testing this on a Microsoft Surface tablet with Windows 10 and Intel HD graphics 4400.

Comment: what's the CPU model?

Comment: @Bahbar: See my edit above (Microsoft Surface tablet with Windows 10 and Intel HD graphics 4400).

Comment: Maybe GLSL 110 does not support gl_ClipVertex? I did not find any information about gl_ClipVertex in GLSL 1.10 specification: https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.10.59.pdf

Comment: Can you post the vertex shader? Maybe the problem is coming from somewhere else, but is ignored when `gl_ModelViewMatrix` or `gl_Vertex` is not used.

Comment: @fordcars The vertex shader code is in the above example assigned to the variable ``VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE`` (a little bit hard to see because of the poor syntax highlighting).

Comment: @Unick NVIDIA or ATI grphics cards execute the example above fine. According to http://mew.cx/glsl_quickref.pdf GLSL 1.1 does support the Vertex Shader variable gl_ClipVertex.

Comment: @denim In my GPU programming practice I faced several times with problem on Intel video cards. It was related special with old video card. Usually my code works on AMD or NVIDIA, but not on Intel. Maybe need to post this question on Intel GPU forum. For one product we did not support Intel video cards long time, because they failed in render with unexpected errors.

Comment: May be no of vertex exceeded the MAX ?
Check if this helps ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891342/please-tell-vertexshader-error-solution